# Ansible Playbook Using Lists/Dictionaries With One Or More Values

Tags: ansible, openshift

I would like to use Ansible to automate OpenShift user creations.

- One or more users may be specified with one password each
- Each user will be joined to one or more groups

I'm currently testing with lists and subelements, and am close.

**vars file**

```
---

host_group: localhost
users:
  - username: jdoe
    password: tester123
    groups:
      - test-group1
  - username: jdosephina
    password: tester456
    groups:
      - test-group2
      - test-group3
```

**test.yaml**

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_group | default('empty_group') }}"
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/vars/openshift_user_creation_vars.yaml
  tasks:

  - name: Create user on master server
    debug:
      msg: "htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd {{ item[0].username }} {{ item[0].password }}"
    become: yes
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ users }}"
      - groups

  - name: Restart atomic service
    debug:
      msg: "systemctl restart atomic-openshift-master-api"
    become: yes

  - name: Add user to group
    debug:
      msg: "oc adm groups add-users {{ item[1] }} {{ item[0].username }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ users }}"
      - groups
```

The issue I have now is if multiple groups are specified (for jdosephina, in this example), the first command to create the user is also run multiple times.

```
TASK [Create user on master server] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd jdoe tester123"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd jdosephina tester456"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd jdosephina tester456"
}

TASK [Restart atomic service] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "systemctl restart atomic-openshift-master-api"
}

TASK [Add user to group] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "oc adm groups add-users test-group1 jdoe"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "oc adm groups add-users test-group2 jdosephina"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "oc adm groups add-users test-group3 jdosephina"
}
```

What would my best method be to run the command that uses groups one or more times based on number of groups, but only run the first command once for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change `{{ item[0].username }} {{ item[0].password }}` in the user creation block to `{{ item.username }} {{ item.password }}`, remove `- groups`, and change `with_subelements` to `with_items`.

Full new playbook:

**test.yaml**

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_group | default('empty_group') }}"
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/vars/openshift_user_creation_vars.yaml
  tasks:

  - name: Create user on master server
    debug:
      msg: "htpasswd -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd {{ item.username }} {{ item.password }}"
    become: yes
    with_items:
      - "{{ users }}"

  - name: Restart atomic service
    debug:
      msg: "systemctl restart atomic-openshift-master-api"
    become: yes

  - name: Add user to group
    debug:
      msg: "oc adm groups add-users {{ item[1] }} {{ item[0].username }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ users }}"
      - groups
```